# Improve this compression algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

I am compressing 8 bit bytes and the algorithm works only if the number of unique single bytes found on the data is 128 or less.

I take all the unique bytes. At the start I store a table containing once each unique byte. If they are 120 I store 120 bytes.

Then, instead of storing each item in space of 8 bits, I store each item in 7 bits, one after another. Those 7 bits contain the item's position on the table.

**Question:** how can I avoid storing those 120 bytes at the start, **by storing the possible tables in my code?**

Comment: You can't, your algorithm is _based_ on that table. You might be interested in the huffman coding which is quite similar to yours: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding

Comment: I can reduce the size of table by 2 ways: a) compressing the table b) store the possible tables in my code. Is b possible?

Comment: no, you are going to have 120! (6.7e198) possible tables to store. If you manage to create always the same table you don't need to send it though

Comment: If the order doesn't matter (and it shouldn't, you could just sort that table), you could store it as 32 bytes (bit-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying do is special case of **huffman coding** where you are only considering unique byte not their frequency hence giving each byte fixed length code but you can do better use their frequency to give them variable length codes using huffman coding and get more compression.

But if you intend to use the same algorithm then consider this way :-

> Dont store 120 bytes store 256 bits (32 bytes) where 1 indicate if value is present
>   because it will give you all info. You use bit to get the values which
>   are found in the file and construct the mapping tables again

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact algorithm, but probably the idea of the compression algorithm is that you cannot. It has to store those values, so it can write a shortcut for all other bytes in the data.

There is one way in which you could avoid writing those 120 bytes: when you know the contents of those bytes beforehand. For example, when you know that whatever you are going to send, will only contain those bytes. Then you can simply make the table known on both sides, and simply store everything but those 120 bytes.

Comment: Fact is, what I describe above is the 2nd pass of compression. That's it: I compress compressed data, so I have no way to know the possible chars. Is there a way to store the possible combinations in the code?

Comment: If you try to store all possible combinations, you would still have to have a way to identify all possible combinations. Of which there are 2^(8*128), which happens to be exactly the same amount of storage space as the bytes that you are storing.

Comment: If you try to store all possible combinations <-- first of all, is this possible?

Comment: If you store this in your code, of course that is possible. But that doesn't mean that it will change anything. You would still have to store 128 bytes to identify the exact combination.

Comment: I can make use of that fact somehow I believe if it's possible but the other guy said: "(6.7e198) possible tables"?

Comment: No, it really is *not* possible to remove those 128 bytes from the compression text. But since you are using compression, it should be insignificant anyway.

Comment: @kokx it is possible to reduce the 128 bytes to 32 bytes using bits to represent if unique byte is present or not.